How to Dynamically Expand Task Groups Based on Output of Upstream Taskfrom different Task group in Airflow 2.9.1?
I'm working with Apache Airflow 2.9.1 and trying to implement dynamic task group expansion based on the output from a task in a different task group.
Here's a sample DAG implementation. In this, I want to use the output from process_param2 in task group tg1 to dynamically expand tasks in task group tg2.
from airflow.decorators import dag, task, task_group
from pendulum import datetime
from airflow.models.baseoperator import chain


@dag(dag_id="dynamic_task_group_example",
    start_date=datetime(2023,1,1),
    schedule=None,
    catchup=False, )
def dynamic_task_group_example():
    @task_group(group_id="group1")
    def tg1():
        @task
        def process_param():
            # This task processes parameters and returns a list
            return ["A", "B", "C"]

        @task
        def process_param2():
            # This task processes parameters and returns a list
            return ["1", "2", "3"]

        processed_params = process_param()
        processed_params2 = process_param2()
        chain(processed_params,
              processed_params2)

    @task_group(group_id="group2")
    def tg2(param):
        @task
        def process(param):
            return f"Further processed {param}"

        process(param)
    processed_params = tg1()
    chain(
        processed_params,
        ###### I should be able to pass output of process_param2 from tg1() group in here
        tg2.expand(param=[1, 2, 4])
    )
dynamic_task_group_example()

I want to:

Get the output list from process_param2 task in tg1
Use that output to dynamically expand the tasks in tg2 using tg2.expand()

How can I access and use the output from process_param2 task to dynamically expand tasks in tg2? Is this possible in Airflow 2.9.1?
